# Can't use .t() function with tensor(weight* [[]])?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I used the

```
tensordata.t()
```

function to transpose the tensor data, but an error occurred.
I tried changing it to `torch.t(tensordata)` and still getting the same error.

I made tensordata by below code:

```
tensordata= self.linear1.weight[:, T.LongTensor(batch_item_index[i].astype(np.int32))]
```

and it looks like this:

```
tensor(1.00000e-03 *
      [[ 1.6500,   ..., -5.2615],
       ...,
       [-1.2557,   ...,   4.1297]])
```

I've been trying to fix it since yesterday, but it still doesn't work. What is the cause of the error? Thank you in advance.

error name:

```
invalid argument 1: out of range at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1524543037166\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensor.cpp:454
```

Comment: Could you provide your `tensordata` creating code with defining the variables `self.linear1, batch_item_index`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. I found the tensordata is empty tensor([[]])!
So I changed the code to handle an exception if tensordata.Size is 0 with below code.
```if tensordata.shape == torch.Size([0]):``` <-- it works.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the tensordata is empty tensor([[]])! So I added the code to handle an exception if tensordata.Size is 0 with below code.

```
if tensordata.shape == torch.Size([0]): 
   continue
```

<-- it works.

Hope this helps someone with the same error.:)